# How to make Facebook App Ads open Play Store instead of my old Android app which doesn't have deep link?

Tags: android, facebook, ads, deep-linking

I'm going to promote my Android application using Facebook App Ads with [Mobile App Engagement](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads-engagement/) objective. I have set up deep linking for the new version of myapp (let's say `v1.1.0`). The old version (`v1.0.0`) is live on Play Store, but it doesn't have deep link implemented yet.

I have created an ad creative in [FB Ads Manager](https://business.facebook.com) and specified an URI for deeplink, for example `myapp://shop`. I send the ad preview to FB app on my device. In case I have myapp `v1.1.0` installed, clicking the ad from FB app launches to shop screen correctly.

The problem is when I still have the old version `v1.0.0`. Obviously, clicking the ad will not direct to shop screen because it doesn't implement deep link yet. However, the FB app is still able to launch myapp to Home screen. How come? Note that `v1.0.0` doesn't have any intent-filter in manifest with `myapp` as the scheme value.

What I want is if user have the old app installed, **the ad should redirect to Play Store instead of opening the old app**, so that user can update from Play Store. Is this possible?

Notes: I already specified the following in FB Developer Settings:

- Google Play Package Name: `com.myapp.app`
- Class Name: `com.myapp.app.Home`
- Deep Linking: Yes

Also, if myapp is not installed, the ad can redirect to Play Store of myapp.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely clear on what method Facebook uses to open installed apps on Android, but it appears that it may be through the app package name rather than the URL scheme. Since your package name hasn't changed between `v1.0.0` and `v1.1.0`, this would explain why the app is still opening even though `v1.0.0` doesn't support the `myapp` URL scheme.

You might be able to bypass this by removing the package name under your app's Settings page on https://developers.facebook.com/apps/:

[image]

In theory, without this the ad would only open the app when the deep link URL successfully opens, and users with `v1.0.0` (or without the app installed at all) would see the Play Store fallback URL instead.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't an option. It must not be left empty for various reasons. So the only way is to add prompt in the old app to notify users to download the new version of the app :)